# Python Heroku App Deployment - not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple "Hello World" Python app in Heroku, but it told me that the deployment is not compatible with buildpack. I've tried to search for the solution in previous similar situation, and did all stuff (e.g. including runtime.txt, requirements.txt etc.) that others can finally solve their problems, but I still have this error message.

Would you pls assist to tell why that happens and how I can get it solved? Many thx!

What I did:-

1. Created hello_4.py
2. In cmd, go to the respective folder, and run “python hello_4.py” and use browser to go to http://localhost:5000/
3. Hello world message successfully appears
4. Ctrl+C to stop the localhost
5. $git init
6. saw the .git folder created
7. $git add .
8. $git commit -m "initial commit 4"
9. $pip freeze > requirements.txt
10. Created Procfile in 1 line: web: gunicorn hello_4:app
11. Created runtime.txt in 1 line: python_version = "3.6.3"
12. $heroku create mthd010 --buildpack heroku/python
13. Successful without error message. Refreshed dashboard in Heroku website, and saw that mthd010 app was created
14. $git push heroku master
15. [error message appears]

My error message: [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olFpr.png)

requirements.txt: [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSPG2.png)

runtime.txt:

```
python_version = "3.6.3"
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn hello_4:app
```

hello_4.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def source():
    html = 'Hello World!'
    return html
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: That requirements.txt file is full of rubbish. Delete everything except "flask".

Comment: Thanks. I tried to remove all the others and just kept 1 line of Flask, but the error message is exactly the same. Also tried to remove and keep all 7 lines of Flask related requirement, but also have the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago I finally got it solved. The problem is mainly due to the runtime.txt.

the updated runtime.txt:-

```
python-3.6.4
```